# convert mysqli to PDO getting errors

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to convert MySQL to pdo but I keep getting an error on the PDO one any ideas what I can be doing wrong. The MySQL is working and I get no errors only pdo I get errors.

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: application/json');



$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employees_db");

$lanId=  $_POST["lanId"];
       $sql="SELECT * FROM  names WHERE LanID='$lanId'   "; 
        $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $rc= $row["FIRSTNAME"]. " " . $row['LASTNAME'];

echo json_encode ($rc);

?>
```

Here is the PDO version.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees_db", 'root', '');
$lanId=  $_POST["lanId"];       
        $params = array( ':LanID' => $lanId);

$pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM names
    WHERE LanID='$LanID'");

$pdo->execute($params);

$result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $rc= $result->FIRSTNAME. " " . $result->LASTNAME;

echo json_encode ($rc);

?>
```

here is Json with ajax that retrieves the last name and first name in textbox name when you type id into lanId textbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#lanId").change(function(){
          var lanId=$(this).val();
           if(lanId != ''){
                  $.ajax({
                              type:"post",
                              url:"insert.php",
                              data:"lanId="+lanId,
                              datatype:"json",
                              success:function(data){ $("#name").val(data);
                                $('#name').css( "background-color","#B3CBD6"  ) 
                               $('#name').animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"});
                               },
                                 error: function(response){
    alert("error scripting")    }

                                                           });
           }
           else{
               $("#name").val("");
               }

          });
     });
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM names
    WHERE LanID='$LanID'");
```

This should be

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM names
    WHERE LanID=:LanID");
```

Then use

`$query->execute($params);`

Have a look at example 2 here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

edit: complete code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees_db", 'root', '');
$lanId=  $_POST["lanId"];       
        $params = array( ':LanID' => $lanId);

$query = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM names
    WHERE LanID=:LanID");

$query->execute($params);

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rc= $result['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $result['LASTNAME'];

echo json_encode ($rc);

?>
```

Comment: I had that originally but changed it to the first example cause I was getting errors. I just changed it back to that and I get this error [22-Nov-2014 19:11:44 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp\www\test\insert.php on line 15

[22-Nov-2014 19:11:44 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[22-Nov-2014 19:11:44 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\test\insert.php:0

Comment: Updated, missed some additional errors.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Did you use `$query->execute` in instead of `$pdo->execute`, as mentioned above?

Comment: still get same error with $query->execute

Comment: sorry different error the box fills with <br /><b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '&quot; &quot;' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in <b>C:\wamp\www\Systems\insert.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

Comment: line 18 is $rc= $result['FIRSTNAME'] " " . $result['LASTNAME'];

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Systems\insert.php on line 18

Comment: Missing a dot `$rc= $result['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $result['LASTNAME'];`